# What is reduplication used for in natural languages?

Tags: conlang-creation, naturalism, morphology, natural-languages

According to [WALS Feature 27A](https://wals.info/feature/27A), 278/368 languages surveyed have productive full and partial reduplication. [Chapter 27](https://wals.info/chapter/27) gives the following example of partial reduplication in Pangasinan:

```
báley "town" -> balbáley "towns"
```

And this example of full reduplication from Sahaptian:

```
té:mul "hail" -> temulté:mul "sleet"
```

But what is reduplication often used to express?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[WALS Chapter 27](https://wals.info/chapter/27) describes a number of functions for reduplication. All examples below come from chapter 27 unless otherwise noted.

## On nouns

Pangasinan uses reduplication to mark plurals:

```
báley "town"
balbáley "towns"
```

Ilocano uses reduplication on nouns to mark a distributive plural:

```
sábong "flower"
sabsábong "various flowers"
```

Ilocano also uses reduplication to turn nouns into reciprocal verbs:

```
bales "revenge"
balembales "to avenge each other"
```

Chukchi uses reduplication to mark the absolutive case:

```
jokwat "eider duck"
jokwajow "eider duck (ABS)"
```

Kayardild uses reduplication to turn nouns into adjectives:

```
kandu "blood"
kandukandu "red"
```

Yawelmani uses reduplication to mark associatives:

```
k'ɔhis  "buttocks"
k'ɔk'ɔhis  "one with large buttocks"
```

## On verbs

Luiseño uses reduplication to mark the number of an inherent object:

```
lawi "to make a hole"
lawlawi "to make two holes"
lawaláwi "to make more than two holes"
```

Mountain Arapesh uses reduplication to mark carelessness on the part of the subject or agent:

```
su "to touch"
susu "to touch all over"
```

Luiseño also uses reduplication to turn a verb into an adjective:

```
lepi "to tan, soften"
lepélpiš "pliable"
```

Ancient Greek used reduplication to mark the perfect aspect ([Ancient Greek Press Book Chapter 42](https://ancientgreek.pressbooks.com/chapter/42)):

```
γράφ "write"
γέγραφ "have written"
```

Tigak uses reduplication to turn a verb into a person who regularly performs that action:

```
giak "send"
gigiak "messenger"
```

## On Adjectives

Turkish uses reduplication to mark intensity:

```
beyaz "white"
bembeyaz "very white"
```

## Automatic Reduplication

Additionally, automatic reduplication is possible, where an affix requires reduplication of the root with no additional meaning. Chapter 27 gives this example from Ilocano:

```
singpet "behave" + agin-
aginsisingpet "pretend to behave"
```

Comment: In Austronesian languages it frequently marks repetitive or progressive aspect.

Comment: The reduplication of adjectives to mark intensity is also found to some extent in Swedish. E.g. "Den är lite lite för stor" - "It is ever so slightly too large", or "En hård hård knut" - "A very hard knot".